# How to create reusable components in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

Ok I really don't know where to start. I have been trying to develop reusable component-like pages in Spring MVC. I ended up using tiles. I had the idea from "Spring in action" book on writing ComponentControllerSupport class. But the problem starts with tile2 and spring 3.0. All old features of tile1 is deprecated and tile2 has changed a lot(like "page" attribute changed into "template" and "controllerClass" changed into "preparer" etc). If anybody knows how to write that "preparer" class or other ways to approach such reusable components please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Spring Roo ? It generates a skeleton of application using best practices that should be good starting point for further development. See http://www.springsource.org/roo/why

Comment: yeah I think I'll play with that later. But right now, I am just too disappointed in how few documentation and examples there is addressing spring "how-to"s. I am wasting too much time on sewing every piece up just to get little thing working. Those framework integration things are really complicated...